# Displaying result in Textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bundle, textview

I'm making an simple app in which users get questions and choose on of the answers(radiobuttons) and in the next activity their score is displayed, the problem is that it doesn't display correct score..

There is my quiz_layout where I have some questions and answers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yourId"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1. HTTP je skraćenica za:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_HyperTextTransferProvider"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hyper Text Transfer Provider"
                android:onClick="fourthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_HyperTranslateTransferProtocol"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hyper Translate Transfer Protocol"
                android:onClick="fourthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_HyperTextTransferProtocol"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hyper Text Transfer Protocol"
                android:onClick="fourthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="fourthRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2. FTP je protokol koji omogućuje:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_morespeed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="veću brzinu download-a velikih datoteka"
                android:onClick="fifthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_transferdata"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="prenos datoteka među računarima na internetu"
                android:onClick="fifthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_controlcomputer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="kontrolu računara putem interneta "
                android:onClick="fifthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="fifthRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>




        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3. Program za crtanje koji dolazi u sklopu Windows operativnog sistema naziva se:"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>


    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_paint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Paint"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_photoshop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Photoshop"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_coreldraw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CorelDraw"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ne znam"
            android:onClick="firstRadioButtons"/>
    </RadioGroup>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4. Kako se nazivaju programi koje korsitimo da bi zaštitili računar od virusa?"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_driveri"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Drajveri"
                android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_antivirusi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Antivirusi"
                android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_editori"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Editori"
                android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="secondRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>



        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5. Skraćenica WWW označava:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_wordwindowweb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Word Window Web"
                android:onClick="thirdRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_worldwideweb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="World Wide Web"
                android:onClick="thirdRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_worldwidthweb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="World Width Web"
                android:onClick="thirdRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="thirdRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6. Prva računarska mreža se nazivala:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_arpanet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ARPANET"
                android:onClick="sixthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_lannet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LANNET"
                android:onClick="sixthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_adslnet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ADSLNET"
                android:onClick="sixthRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="sixthRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7. AutoCAD je vrsta programa koja služi za:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>


        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_uredjivanje"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Uređivanje fotografija"
                android:onClick="seventhRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_crtanje"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Crtanje likovnih crteža"
                android:onClick="seventhRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_projektovanje"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tehničko projektovanje"
                android:onClick="seventhRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="seventhRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8. Mrežna struktura na slici je:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mrezna"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_razgranata"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Razgranata"
                android:onClick="eightRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_magistrala"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Magistrala"
                android:onClick="eightRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pravolinijska"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pravolinijska"
                android:onClick="eightRadioButtons"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_dontknow8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ne znam"
                android:onClick="eightRadioButtons"/>
        </RadioGroup>




        <Button
            android:text="Potvrdi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:onClick="nextButton"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my quiz_activity where I calculate my points:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;



public class quiz_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int points = 0;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Test");
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Osnovne škole");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }


    public void firstRadioButtons(View view) {

        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {


            case R.id.radio_paint:
                if (checked)
                    points += 2;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_photoshop:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_coreldraw:
                if (checked)
                    --points;

                break;
        }

    }
    public void secondRadioButtons(View view) {

        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_driveri:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_editori:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_antivirusi:
                if (checked)
                    points += 2;
                break;
        }

    }
    public void thirdRadioButtons(View view) {

        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_wordwindowweb:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_worldwideweb:
                if (checked)
                    points += 2;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_worldwidthweb:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
        }

    }
    public void fourthRadioButtons(View view) {

        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_HyperTextTransferProvider:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_HyperTranslateTransferProtocol:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_HyperTextTransferProtocol:
                if (checked)
                    points += 2;
                break;
        }

    }
    public void fifthRadioButtons(View view) {

        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_morespeed:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_transferdata:
                if (checked)
                    points += 2;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_controlcomputer:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
        }

    }
    public void sixthRadioButtons(View view) {

        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_arpanet:
                if (checked)
                    points = +2;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_lannet:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_adslnet:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
        }

    }
    public void seventhRadioButtons(View view) {

        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_uredjivanje:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_crtanje:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_projektovanje:
                if (checked)
                    points += 2;
                break;
        }

    }
    public void eightRadioButtons(View view) {

        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio_razgranata:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_magistrala:
                if (checked)
                    points += 2;
                break;
            case R.id.radio_pravolinijska:
                if (checked)
                    --points;
                break;
        }

    }
    public void nextButton(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(quiz_activity.this, score_activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("some_key", points);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    }
```

When user answers all questions right it says that they have 6 points, while they actually have 16..

---

Here is score_layout where it should be displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vaš rezultat na ovom testu je:"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>


        </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="/16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/score1"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>



</LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/all_rights"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And score_activity where I get Bundle sent from quiz_activity and display it in my TextView:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class score_activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.score_layout);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int points = bundle.getInt("some_key");

        TextView scoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        scoreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(points));
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of things, but nothing worked..

Comment: Step through your code and see why the score is calculated incorrectly. This is way too much for someone else to wade through

Comment: Everything is fine when I answer one by one question and go on next activity to see score, but when the score is >10 there is a problem..

Comment: If you debug the code, is the value for the score variable calculated correctly, and simply not displayed correctly? Or is it not calculated correctly when it's over 10

Comment: Could it be that when the text in the textView is changed the size isn't recalculated and it hence cuts the first didget of?

Comment: In the logcat it says 6, there is something wrong with my code then, but can't figure out..

Comment: I typed points= +2 in one question and it returned me on 2, thank you all..